# Converting multipoint geometry to ONE single point using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry-conversion, multipart, multipoint

I have an ArcGIS file geodatabase with two featureClasses.

One is a point featureClass which represents the centroids of the cells of a regular grid.

The second represents the corners of each grid cell. This is a multipoint of up to four points per location, because of neighbouring grid cells.

I need to append the centroids to the corners (so that five points can later be associated (by 'nearest') with point data in each grid cell).

But ArcGIS will not permit the point geometry to be appended to the multipoint geometry.

What I do not want is to get an exploded multipoint featureClass, with up to four points per location. Perhaps this could be an interim step, with points 2,3 and 4 subsequently deleted.

What I do want is for each 'corner' to be represented by a single point.

Answer (score 7):

I seem to have found the answer.

Within ArcToolbox, Feature to Point seems to do the trick.

Converts 1 multipoint to 1 singlepoint.